# E3D-v6 hotend on MK8 extruder

Tags: e3d-v6, makerbot-mk8

I have an MK8<sup>Makerbot(?)</sup> extruder on my HICTOP branded printer.

The problem with the E3D hotend is that the heatbreak is shorter and doesn't protrude through the top of the heatsink. Therefore I can't mount it to the motor mount.

[image: Photograph of printhead]

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is your question? You obviously need to make some adapter or redesign the extruder. Do you want somebody to give you the model file? Have you tried searching on model repositories (e.g. thingiverse, youmagine, etc...)?

Comment: http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1798616/#comments Like this one? but am confused as to how he got it to mount onto the motor mount

Comment: This looks like an Anet A8. Replace the whole x carriage.

Comment: @James Trotter I figured as much but was looking for a 2nd opinion. If you change your comment to answer, I will be more than happy to accept it. Now all I got to do is to print a mount for the inductive sensor since the nozzle in no longer in the same position due to the shorter heatbreak. DOH! Should of saw that coming. I need new glasses!!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with the heatbreak? have you removed the heatsink from the E3D and are just trying to put the heatbreak/block straight in to the bottom of MK8 extruder? You will lose _all_ benefits of the E3D by doing this, as the heatsink/fan assembly of the V6 is what makes it perform so great. The Anet A8's stock cooling at the "cold end" is terrible, I cant see you getting any benefit without the full heatsink from E3D. I've written up a full answer that hopefully explains what you need to do, i can get the files i used if you need them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, I have the same printer and am speaking from my experiences.

You have two routes you can take with this, but both are effectively the same result - you need to replace the X carriage.

If you want to re-use your existing extruder components you can pull the MK8 extruder off the X carriage and use it as the extruder to drive a bowden configuration, then all you need is a length of PTFE tube and the couplers between the E3d and the MK8 to hold the tube. This is probably the best solution as it takes a lot of weight off of the X-carriage resulting in significantly better print quality, the only downside is that printing with flexible filaments is a *lot* more difficult with a bowden configuration, if you intended to do a lot of that.

The other option (and the one I took) is to print an entire new x-carriage/extruder assembly. Because the Anet A8 is based off the Prusa and the Z/X carriage assemblies are *basically* the same as the original Prusa I3 you can just take any design for the Prusa and fit it onto the Anet, I did this with a gregs wade extruder & E3D hotend mount I found on thingiverse.

I didnt look too hard, but if you are adament on wanting to keep the MK8 extruder on the X-carriage and couple it direct-driven to the V6, you can probably find some x-carriage that lines the two up for this purpose (or you could even design one yourself if you are interested in doing so). I didn't look in to this route myself, so cannot give much guidance.

Comment: I use and would recommend the following parts: Integrated extruder solution with easy to mount accessory block and good locking of the hot end: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1383913 Simple but prolific and reliable X carriage: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:184933